# javascript animation of content

Tags: javascript, animation, text

my question is about making all of the content on my webpage move when I go through different sections of the site. For example I am in the Home page and click on Contact, all the text,pictures,div tags, etc. should move left and out of the screen and the new info (from Contacts) should move from the right and to the middle of the screen where it should be. Something like a transition on a presentation... I think it should be something simple, but I'd appreciate if someone points me in the right direction. Thanks!

Comment: Check here http://bartaz.github.io/impress.js/#/bored

Comment: I guess if you want to annoy your visitors, go ahead…

Answer (score 0):

Not simple, but check out jQuery and animate:
http://api.jquery.com/animate/